# Allow the conversion a class instance into `Decimal` type

Tags: python, operator-overloading, decimal

Suppose I implement a class which maintains a `Decimal` value, and I'd like to be able to convert an instance of that class into `Decimal` type.

For example, given:

```
from decimal import Decimal

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = Decimal(data)

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.data)
```

I can convert an instance of `MyClass` into `int` type:

```
x = MyClass(42)
y = int(x)
print(y)
```

How can I extend this class, such that I will be able to do something like:

```
x = MyClass(42)
y = Decimal(x)
print(y)
```

?

The official documentation starting [more or less here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__) seems relevant to my question.

But it doesn't quite provide a solution to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The docs of [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) state that the argument can be

> an integer, string, tuple, float, or another Decimal object.

So if your object is something else, then it won't work.

Another approach is to implement a `to_decimal` function for the `MyClass` class which converts the instance to `Decimal`:

```py
class MyClass:
    ...

    def to_decimal(self) -> Decimal:
        return ...  # return whatever is appropriate
```

Alternatively, you can have `MyClass` subclass `Decimal`, i.e.:

```py
class MyClass(Decimal):
    ...
```

Then `Decimal(x)` will actually work.

Comment: Note, if you're going to subclass `Decimal`, you should not have a separate `data` attribute to store the value. `self` *is* the value in that approach. A separate `data` attribute would be redundant and lead to confusion and desync bugs.